# When is the union of a closed set and a open set open?

Tags: general-topology

say $A$ is an open set, and $B$ is a closed set. IF $B \subset A$ then their union is open.

I think this is the only case when $A \cup B$ is open. Because if $B$ has an element $p\in B$ and $p \not \in A$ then we can find a $$

Comment: When the boundary of the closed set is contained within the open set?

Comment: Is this in $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Let $A = (0,1)\cup(1,2)$ and $B = \{1\}$. Then $A \cup B = (0,2)$ but $B \not\subset A$.

Comment: Or take any non-empty open set $A$ with non-empty complement $B$

Comment: Let $A=(1,3)\cup(4,6)$ and $B=[2,5]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=(0,1)$ in $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology.  Let $B=(-\infty,0]$ which is closed because it is the complement of the open $(0,\infty)$.  Then $A \cup B=(-\infty,1)$ which is open.

Answer (score 1):

In the discrete topology, every subset is open and closed. Thus the union of an open subset and a closed subset is always open.